# Python, magic and objects that add attributes to its owner

Tags: design-patterns, python, django

Let me start with a disclaimer: I'm *not* the best programmer out there. I *do* however study I.T. and learnt a bit of Java and C.

I'm getting stuck into Python and Django + Mongoengine, I'm not going to explain it into detail as it will deviate from the original question.

While trying to understand what is happening at [this bit of Django code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L136) I was **shocked** by some of concepts I seemed to understand.

Mostly I was completely confused by how one object could add accessible attributes to a parent object and how Python defines `__set__()` and `__get__()` in such a way as to be so confusing as that.

Could someone tell me how *orthodox* this design style is and whether I find it bizarre because I'm an amateur programmer.

Comment: Hi Martijn, what I mean is the lack of obvious object initialization, then the object's set() and get() are used in a very strange manner, basically set() changes what the owner of the object returns!

Comment: Hey Gnat, thanks for the comment. Perhaps my question should mention: How Pythonic does that bit of code look to you guys? To me it's **incredibly** unreadable / hard to follow.

Comment: Could you describe what you find odd? There are various things going on there, and your description "in such a way" is rather vauge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking at a *descriptor*. Descriptors are special types of objects that can alter their behaviour when bound to a Python class or instance. They give you a hook into class and instance attribute interactions (setting, getting and deleting).

Python functions and the [`property` decorator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) are descriptors. Functions have a `__get__` method that returns a method wrapper when accessed; this is how Python methods can pass in the `self` parameter when you call a method on an instance. `property` objects have `__get__`, `__set__` and `__del__` methods to handle attribute interactions and translate those interactions into method calls.

The [`FileDescriptor` class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L136) you linked to, translates attribute access into a lookup for the named field on the instance they are bound to, guaranteeing that a `FieldFile` object is returned. It acts as a *proxy* for the field, and it is therefor completely natural that they change the named field on the instance they are bound to.

See the [Descriptor HOWTO Guide](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html)  and the [Implementing Descriptors](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) section of the Python Datamodel documentation for more details.

Comment: Martijn that's a fantastic answer thanks so much. You know, this concept of descriptors is exactly the kind of thing I reckon separates amateurs, from proper Software Engineers. Could I also bother you to help me with this: [Stack Overflow Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862912/mongoengine-filefield-saving-to-disk)

Comment: I am not familiar with Mongo at all, so not sure I can be of help there.